# The data appears successfully in the console But when displayed on the page the error appears ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: angular

The data appears successfully in the console But when displayed on the page the error appears:

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and
>   iterables are allowed services

```
 getdetails(id:number) : Observable<INewsModule>{
return  this._HttpClient.get<INewsModule>('http://localhost:1858/api/details/' + id)
}
```

**component**

```
private  items:any= [];  
ngOnInit() {
    let id : number = this._activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this._NewsService.getdetails(id).subscribe(items =>{ 
    this.items=items;
      console.log(items);
} );
```

**html**

```
<table class="table">
<caption>List of users</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">NameNews</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let details of items">
<th scope="col">  {{details.NameNews}}
</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**interface**

```
  export class INewsModule{
IDNews:number;
IDCategoery:number; 
NameNews:string; 
TopicNews:string; 
DateNews?:Date;
ImageCaption:string;
ImageName:string ;
 }
```

Comment: Does your `console.log(items);` print an Object or an Array? You can iterate over an Array in your template, you will have to do something extra if you want to loop over Objects

Comment: can you post what you get on console.log(items)

Comment: Angular prints `[object Object]` when rendering an object literal to the DOM unless you use the `JSON` pipe.

Comment: `getdetails(id:number) : Observable<INewsModule>` 

Above block in your code returns a 'INewsModule' not an array. can you type that to an array?

Comment: xyz https://i.imgur.com/kjGMbQl.png  Object
DateNews: "2010-01-10T00:00:00"
IDCategoery: 6
IDNews: 16
ImageCaption: "xls194454633.png"
ImageName: "xls194454633.png"
NameNews: "re"
TopicNews: "jh"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Ashok https://i.imgur.com/kjGMbQl.png Object
DateNews: "2010-01-10T00:00:00"
IDCategoery: 6
IDNews: 16
ImageCaption: "xls194454633.png"
ImageName: "xls194454633.png"
NameNews: "re"
TopicNews: "jh"
__proto__: Object

Comment: The Head Rush how can use pipe

Comment: Vivek Natarajan export class INewsModule{

   IDNews:number;
   IDCategoery:number; 
   NameNews:string; 
   TopicNews:string; 
   DateNews?:Date;
     ImageCaption:string;
    ImageName:string ;


}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that while you have typed `items` as an array,
the service is actually returning a single object.

Perhaps the object that your service is returning contains an array,
and you need to do something like:

```
this._NewsService.getdetails(id).subscribe(response => { 
    this.items = response.items;
    console.log(this.items);
});
```

Watch the 'network' tab in the browser's developer tools, 
and see what the JSON response looks like.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UTkJpVW.png      this.items = response.items;
  show error response.items Property 'items' does not exist on type 'INewsModule'.ts(2339)

Comment: this._NewsService.getdetails(id).subscribe(response =>{ 
    
  this.items = response.IDNews;
  console.log(this.items);
in console show id 16  but in html show error Error trying to diff '16'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Answer (score 0):

**solved**

services

```
getdetails(id:number): Observable <INewsModule[]>{
return   this.http.get('http://localhost:1858/api/details/' + 
id).map((response: Response)=><INewsModule[]>response.json());
}
```

Component

```
items : INewsModule[];
subscription: ISubscription;
statusMessage: string = 'please wait Loading data ... ';

 .................

let id : number = this._activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this._NewsService.getdetails(id).retryWhen((err) => {
      return err.scan((retryCount) =>{
retryCount +=1;
if(retryCount < 6 ){
this.statusMessage ='Retrying .....Attept #' + retryCount;
return retryCount;
} else {
throw (err);
}
}, 0).delay(1000)
})
.subscribe((newsdata) => {
if(newsdata == null){
  this.statusMessage = 'news does not exist';
} else {
    this.items = newsdata
}

},
(error) =>{
  this.statusMessage = "please try again after sometime"
  console.log(error);
})
```

Html

```html
<table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th colSpan='2'>News Details</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
   
   <td>
   <label class="label label-default">
   Name news 
   </label>    {{items.NameNews}} 
   </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```